# how can I make two divs horizotal and two divs vertical in mobile version?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a layout that beings with a title, subtitle, and then make a two divs row horizontal then two divs vertical for the mobile version, but how can I make them properly without getting cut off the paragraph of the div `A`?

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3FFl.png)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                  <div data-v-ea542cec="" class="detail-header">
                      <h2 data-v-ea542cec="" class="title">
                          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Donec eget turpis commodo, ullamcorper ligula ac, fer</font></font>
                      </h2>
                      <p data-v-ea542cec="" class="tit-desc">
                          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Donec eget turpis commodo</font></font>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look here

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  
  margin: 4px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                  <div data-v-ea542cec="" class="detail-header">
                      <h2 data-v-ea542cec="" class="title">
                          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Donec eget turpis commodo, ullamcorper ligula ac, fer</font></font>
                      </h2>
                      <p data-v-ea542cec="" class="tit-desc">
                          <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Donec eget turpis commodo</font></font>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
    
          </div>
          
          <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                       <div class="content">
                               content a

                       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="content">
                               content b

                       </div>
      </div>
          </div>
     
    
</div>
```

Comment: sure, but it only keeps the mobile version, while it should be two divs in the same row, and vertical on mobile that's what I want to try out

Comment: have you seen this example that i've made where the bootstrap is included?  https://jsfiddle.net/w8bsxzt3/18/

Comment: you don't have bootstrap included in the code snippet from stackoverflow.

Comment: woops. sorry I forgot to include it . it works like a charm.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to achieve what you have in that picture. you don't really need bootstrap for this, if you use flex.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .content-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
}

.content-wrapper .content-A, .content-B {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
  Here goes the title
  </h1>
  <h4>
  here goes the subtitle
  </h4>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-A">
      here is content for card A
    </div>
    <div class="content-B">
      here is content for card B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if its using bootstrap. how would u do it?

Comment: i've post an answer above. and here you have a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w8bsxzt3/18/